# Install lastest (10th) version of ngx-bootstrap for Angular 15

Tags: angular, npm, ngx-bootstrap

Official website says that 10th ngx-boostrap is compatible with 15th Angular:

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/documentation#getting-started

Angular (14.x.x - 15.x.x)
ngx-bootstrap (10.0.0)

But when I attempt to install it (**npm install ngx-bootstrap@latest**) I take an error:
[image]

eresolve-report.txt:

[image]

Am I installing it in a wrong way? Or how there could be unresolved dependency in packages that should be compatible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this moment, ngx-bootstrap@latest is 9.0.0, 10.0.0 is @next.

Additionally version 10 still has peerDependencies for Angular 14 (probably not intentionally), so it can't be installed without --force or --legacy-peer-deps.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap/v/10.0.0?activeTab=explore

Comment: Thanks. Also I found this issue on their github: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/6527

Answer (score 0):

try with this: `npm install ngx-bootstrap@latest --legacy-peer-deps.`

It worked for me hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

The following command works for **angular 15**:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap@latest --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: you're going to run into other issues with package-lock.json changing a lot of peer deps.